# Seeking a source for Keruvim as destructive angels vs saintly children

Tags: sources-mekorot, malach-angel, chinuch-education

I was wondering if anyone could please help me - I am seeking the source for the following vort:

The Keruvim in Bereishis are described as destructive angles guarding gan eden, but we know them also as the two saintly children on top of the aron kodesh. The idea being that children can either be destructive or saintly it’s in the hands of the parents to ensure that the right result comes out.

I have seen this idea written in the name of Rav Yaakov Kamenetsky zt"l, firstly in the notes of the Artscroll stone edition Chumash Bereishis 3:24 as well as [here](https://torah.org/torah-portion/drasha-5757-terumah/). However I have checked in the Emes L'Yaakov al HaTorah and also on Gemoro Sukka where it talks about the height of Aron Kodesh and the Keruvim, and I'm yet to see it. Was it just something he said in a shmuess or is it actually recorded somewhere?

I have also seen it b'sheim R’ Moshe Mordechai Epstein zt”l, Rosh Yeshiva of Knesses Yisroel Slabodka - but I wouldn't know where to begin on that front?

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I believe Artscroll was quoting Emes LeYaakov

Comment: [An article on Hidabroot](https://www.hidabroot.org/article/103820) cites this idea in the name of R' Meir Shapira.

Comment: Please can I have proper sources specified.

Comment: I saw this brought in a few seforim all said it "bshem" so the chances of finding it in their respective works is very minimal in my opinion

Comment: Thanks sam that's what I think too.